# Vue: Can we use Object tag with a property of HTML4 like 'classid' in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html4

I want to convert some sources that worked in maybe HTML4 to Vue.js source.
As I know the property `'classid'` in `<object>` tag is removed in HTML5.

Can we use HTML4 in Vue.js? and How to use this `<object>` tag in this case?

These are the sample sources of the html4

**API_Test01.html**

```
<html>
    <object classid='clsid:AnUUID' id='FOO'></object>
    <script language="javascript">
        function bar()
        {
            var ret = FOO.bar()
            alert(ret)
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form name="frm">
            <APIs used when CS interlocking><br>
            ND status: <input type="button" value="bar" onClick="bar()"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LoginTestEnc.html**

`clsid:AnUUID` is same with AI_Test01.html's

```
<script language="javascript">
try{
    var sampleObj = new ActiveXObject("IniSX.SClient.1");
}catch(e){
    alert("Please try again after SSO Client program installation->Business authentication login. Go to the program manual installation screen.");
    self.location.replace("http://sso.the.url/SCInstall.html");
}

</script>

<!-- Sample Client Object ID-->
<OBJECT ID="SAMPLE_API" CLASSID="CLSID:AnUUID"  width=0 height=0></OBJECT>

<script language="javascript">

    //Extract SSO Ticket and update APP_ID access history
    var ticket = SAMPLE_API.GetTicketAppWithEnc("APP_ID"); 

    //Get authentication information from client
    //Response code Success: authentication ticket, Failure: 2: Status before login

    if(ticket.length==1){
        if(ticket==2 ){
            alert("Login Please");
        }
        SAMPLE_API.OpenLogin("www.the.url",ticket);
        //Since you are not logged in, go to the address after calling the authentication window
        noConfirmClose();

    }else{
        
        alert( ticket);

    }
function noConfirmClose(){
    top.window.open('about:blank','_self').close();
    top.window.opener=self;
    top.self.close();
}
</script>
```